# How to Concatenate a cell including text with a cell including an emoji in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to concatenate 2 cells... 1 including text, 1 including an emoji...

Cell A1:
my nice text

Cell B1:

I am trying to get the following on Cell C1:
my nice text

So I entered the following formula in cell C1:
=concatenate(A1, " ", B1)

This gives an empty cell.

How should be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

For cell `C1` you can use the `&` in the following formula instead:

```
=A1&" "&B1
```